# Get the sum of elements of an ArrayList

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I'm trying to get the sum of the elements of an ArrayList.

I've only been able to print the numbers, but not the sum.

Right now it shows `1,1,1,1,1` which equals 5, and that is the correct number. But I want it to display `5` instead.

```
ArrayList <history> history = historyDAO.getHistory(x, y);
ArrayList <Integer> totalWins = new ArrayList <Integer> ();

for (history his : history) {
       String res = his.getRes();
             if (res.equals("Vundet")) {
                    int totalW = 0; 
                    totalW++;
                    totalWins.add(totalW);
              System.out.print(totalWins);
}}
```

For good mesure I'll mention that the `ArrayList<history>` refers to a class that stores all the data. Now I only want to process objects from there where the `res`value is equal to `Vundet`.

Comment: Move the `System.out` out of the loop..?

Comment: what does your history "class" look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `sum` of the elements as your question states,  you can use streams.

```
int sum = history.stream()
    .filter(his->his.getRes().equals("Vundet"))
    .mapToInt(his->his.getWins()) // assuming this getter exists.
    .sum();
```

Comment: Thank you! As you and Karol pointed out earlier, the streams solve my problem. As I said im still kinda new, so I did not have alot of experience with streams. Is this assumed to be a correct way of doing this?

Comment: This is one way of doing it.  Streams are there to help, not dictate. You could also do it with loops which would be fine.  But there is insufficient information  in your question to answer it precisely.  What exactly are you taking the sum of?

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you are trying to count "Vundet" entries. This can be done by incrementing a counter variable:

```
int count = 0;
for (history his : history) {
  if (his.getRes().equals("Vundet")) {
    count++;
  }
}
System.out.println(count);
```

You can also write it using [Java streams](https://winterbe.com/posts/2014/07/31/java8-stream-tutorial-examples/):

```
long count = history.stream()
    .map(history::getRes)
    .filter("Vundet"::equals)
    .count();
```

Comment: Thank you - but this does not seem to work either. Now i get 12345 in the System.out.print. I want to get the sum which equals to 5.

Comment: The code above prints a single value, there is only one call to `System.out.println` outside of the loop. You have miss-typed something in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here is the problem:
totalW is a variable you are using to count the occurence, you are good till here. Only issue is declaration of this variable making it 0 should be above, other wise its like counting 1, and then resetting to 0 and then again counting 1, instead of going to 2.

Another issue is you want to print the value of this variable in the end instead of every time you count so here is the final one:

```
ArrayList <history> history = historyDAO.getHistory(x, y);
ArrayList <Integer> totalWins = new ArrayList <Integer> ();

for (history his : history) {
   String res = his.getRes();
         int totalW = 0; 
         if (res.equals("Vundet")) {

                totalW++;
                totalWins.add(totalW);

}System.out.print(totalWins);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is printing `[1,1,1,1,1]` because you are printing `totalWinds` which is a `List`.

If you want to print how many times `history.getRes().equals("Vundet")` happends, then you could, or move `int totalW = 0;` out of the loop or use the stream option.

totalW out of the loop.

```
ArrayList <History> history = historyDAO.getHistory(x, y);

int totalW = 0; // Out of the loop so it does not get initialize every iteration
for (history his : history) {
    String res = his.getRes();
    if (res.equals("Vundet")) {
        totalW++;
    }
}
System.out.println(totalW);
```

Or with streams.

```
ArrayList <History> history = historyDAO.getHistory(x, y);
long total = history.stream()
                .filter(his -> his.getRes() != null && !his.getRes().isEmpty() && his.getRes().equals("Vundet"))
                .count();
```